# Create a hash from a map result

Tags: ruby

I need to create a hash using the key_name and value from a set of results.

It would be clear if I show you what I have:

```
results.map{|r| {r.other_model.key_name=>r.value} }
```

that is giving me this:

```
[{"api_token"=>"stes"}, {"Name"=>"nononono"}]
```

But I want this:

```
{"api_token"=>"stes", "Name"=>"nononono"}
```

What is the most beautiful way to do this on ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do as below using [`Hash::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D)

```
Hash[results.map { |r| [r.other_model.key_name,r.value] } ]
```

In Ruby 2.1.0, we have [`Hash#to_h`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-to_h)

```
results.map { |r| [r.other_model.key_name,r.value] }.to_h
```

or use [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)

```
results.each_with_object({}) { |r,h| h[ r.other_model.key_name ] = r.value }
```

Comment: What?  No tap?  `{}.tap { |h| results.each { |r| h[ r.other_model.key_name ] = r.value } }`.  If you like the sound of `tap`, as I do, `{}.tap{}.tap{}.tap { |h|... }` also works.

Answer (score 1):

So far my best approach is this:

```
Hash[results.map{|r| [r.other_model.key_name, r.value] } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results.inject({}){|h, r| h[r.other_model.key_name] = r.value; h}
```

This is more efficient than other answers that create an intermediate array and then convert it to a hash.

Comment: Am I the only one bugged by `; h`?  How about `merge` instead? (If you wish to say, "get over it", go ahead--I can take it.)